# xsl:for-each not working for child nodes?

Tags: xslt, foreach

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service>
    <Author name="Raymond">
        <Book>Master Mind</Book>
        <Book>Big Bites</Book>
    </Author>
    <Author name="CLAYTON">
        <Book>Beyond the RACK</Book>
    </Author>
</Service>`
```

using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Author">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            <xsl:for-each select="//Book">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

expected output:

```
Raymond Master Mind Big Bites CLAYTON Beyond the RACK
```

Comment: @rap-2-h Please do not change the OP's expected output (or add niceties).

Answer (score 2):

Use a relative path `select="Book"` for the inner `for-each`

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Book">
```

selects *all* Book nodes in the entire document, starting from the `/` root node. To select only Books that are children of the current Author, try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Book">
```

--
**Note**: It's not clear to me on what basis do you expect white spaces to be inserted in-between the values written to the output.